# avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x17

Tags: arduino-uno

Every time I try to upload code to my arduino I always get this error : avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x17. How do i fix it ?

Comment: @Juraj Mine is 0x17 the other one is 0x00

Comment: nothing special for 0x17

Comment: @Juraj Different responses = different error

Comment: it is not an error code. it is a random value received instead of expected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community! I'm not able to comment yet so i'll answer here.
Try changing the connection to other USB port.
If that doesnt work check this question, the solutions can be similar (Juraj is right in the comments) : 
[avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00," aka Some Dude Named Avr Won't Let Me Upload My Program](http://%22avrdude:%20stk500_getsync():%20not%20in%20sync:%20resp=0x00,%22%20aka%20Some%20Dude%20Named%20Avr%20Won't%20Let%20Me%20Upload%20My%20Program)

Good Luck!

Comment: Comments are not for answering, so you did the right thing by posting an answer. :)